# get a variable number from sql

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework, pear

I'm a beginner in php. I'm trying get a variable number from sql  ,

I have this part of code:

```
function renderNotification()
{
    if ($user_id = $this->getDi()->auth->getUserId()) {
        $cnt = $this->getDi()->db->selectCell("SELECT COUNT(ticket_id) FROM ?_helpdesk_ticket WHERE status IN (?a) AND user_id=?",
                array(HelpdeskTicket::STATUS_AWAITING_USER_RESPONSE), $user_id);

        if ($cnt)
            return '<div class="am-info">' . ___('You have %s%d ticket(s)%s that require your attention',
                sprintf('<a href="%s">', REL_ROOT_URL . '/helpdesk/index/p/index/index?&_user_filter_s[]=awaiting_user_response'), $cnt, '</a>') .
            '</div>';
    }
}
```

i want get number of ticket only in other place in my program

This is my try:

```
  <?php echo "%s%d"  ; ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo $cnt  ; ?>
```

but not work
i'm using Zend , sf , pear , all what i need output %s%d ticket(s)%s from above code in other place or call it

Comment: What is the library you use? It's not obvious and no function like `selectCell` exists in plain PHP. (And depending on the library, the query might not be completely correct as `?_helpdesk_ticket` looks just strange.)

Comment: @jso i'm using Zend , sf , pear , all what i need output %s%d ticket(s)%s from above code in other place or call it

Comment: Then correctly specify the used libs in the question directly.

Comment: try to dump your $cnt variable using var_dump function

Comment: @siddhesh i'm traying this but not work  
  <?php var_dump ($cnt -> getMethods()); ?>

Comment: you can try by using exit() function after dumping value actually I don't know your framework so I can't guide you much detail rather than just doing simple debugging. if there is some error logging mechanism in your framework  try checking logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found correct way it's below

```
<?php
$cnt = $di->db->selectCell("SELECT COUNT(ticket_id)
        FROM ?_helpdesk_ticket
        WHERE status IN (?a)
        AND user_id=?",
    array(HelpdeskTicket::STATUS_AWAITING_USER_RESPONSE),
    $di->user->pk());
echo $cnt;
?>
```